# How can I use Kazam Screencaster In Terminal?

Tags: gnome-terminal, screencast, kazam

I want to operate ***Kazam*** in terminal. Is there any command to start ***kazam*** and start screencasting instantly?

(I am not questing the command `kazam --silent`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I came across is exactly using `kazam --silent` in combination with `xdotool`, by creating a function and putting it in `~/.bashrc`:

```
k () { 
 kazam --silent &> /dev/null & 
 sleep 1 
 xdotool key 'Super+Ctrl+r'; 
}
```

Now every time I run `k` kazam runs and starts recording, we can use <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> to Pause/Resume recording and  <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> to stop recording.